# Singular form for cattle

Tags: grammatical-number

A female elephant is called a cow, a male elephant is called a bull. When talking about this animal we use the gender generic term, elephant. The plural of this is elephants.

Now think about cattle. A female is called a cow, the male is called a bull. The gender generic term is cattle. However, this only hold true for the plural form.

**Is there a gender generic singular word for cattle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, perhaps surprisingly, there is no single singular word for *cattle* (in fact, *cattle* can correctly refer to herds of bison, although this usage is less common).

*Cow*, *bull*, *heifer*, and *calf* are the singular words for domestic cattle, and if you don't know the sex of the animal, you'd just guess and call it a cow or a bull.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

"*I see a bovine standing in the field."*

NOTE:

There is also an associated adjective.

However from:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cow

There some usage of the word *"cow"* to refer to:

"2 :a domestic bovine animal regardless of sex or age"

Comment: great answer, although not exactly what I'm looking for as bovine is not specific to cattle and is a broader term.

Comment: Note that *bovine* can also refer to bison.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie  See my edit.